# Python3 subprocess communicate example

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I'm new to subprocessing.

I just need a really simple win32 example of communicate() between a **parent.py** and **child.py**. A string sent from parent.py to child.py, altered by child.py and sent back to parent.py for print() from parent.py.


I'm posting this because examples I have found end up either not being win32 or not using a child which just confuses me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a simple example as per your requirements. This example is Python 3.x (slight modifications are required for 2.x).

### parent.py

```
import subprocess
import sys

s = "test"
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "child.py"],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, _ = p.communicate(s.encode())
print(out.decode())
```

### child.py

```
s = input()
s = s.upper()
print(s)
```

I wrote and tested this on Mac OS X. There is no platform-specific code here, so there is no reason why it won't work on Win32 also.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. It does not seem to be accepting raw_input. probably because I'm using python 3. I tried to change it to input but this raised another error 'EOFError: EOF when reading a line'.

Comment: Ok, I'll modify the example for Python 3.x.

Comment: i still seem to get ...
self.stdin.write(input) ... TypeError: must be bytes or buffer, not str

Comment: You will need `p.communicate(s.encode())` as I wrote above. This is because Python 3 strings are Unicode and must be encoded before writing to a pipe (and decoded after reading).

Comment: ahh i see now. needed to refresh page. thanks a million. unfortunatly i cant give you that many reps but it looks like you have plenty :P

Comment: hey I know this is a bit of an addition but ... if I wanted child.py to be a binary file I get 'SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with ... but no encoding declared'. How can I change parent.py to deal with .exe files?

Comment: oh I just removed 'sys.executable' and that seemed to do the trick

Comment: Yup, `sys.executable` is the path to the current Python binary.