# Python 3 subprocess pipe blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

In python 2.7, this works and returns the expected string `it works!`

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash'], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write('echo it works!\n')
print process.stdout.readline()
```

When I know try this in python 3.4 it gets stuck at the readline command

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash'], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write(bytes('echo it works!\n','UTF-8'))
print(process.stdout.readline().decode('UTF-8'))
```

Comment: May be this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3

Comment: I was surprised to find that adding `process.stdin.flush()` fixes the problem. I thought it would be line buffered.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652767/python3-subprocess-communicate-example). Also @tdelaney's comment...

Comment: thanks for your help. the `process.stdin.flush()` works. But the answer is a little more elegant than always have to flush it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint about buffering is helpfull. The following information can be found in the Subprocess library module documentation:

> bufsize will be supplied as the corresponding argument to the open()
> function when creating the stdin/stdout/stderr pipe file objects:
>
> 0 means unbuffered (read and write are one system call and can return short)
>
> 1 means line buffered (only usable if universal_newlines=True i.e., in a text mode)

and

> If universal_newlines is False the file objects stdin, stdout and
> stderr will be opened as binary streams, and no line ending conversion
> is done.
>
> If universal_newlines is True, these file objects will be opened as
> text streams in universal newlines mode using the encoding returned by locale.getpreferredencoding(False)

Putting it all together gives the following Python3 code:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash'], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
process.stdin.write('echo it works!\n')
print(process.stdout.readline())
```